# How to resize images when a radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, html, image

I am having some issues when trying to resize a pizza. The radio buttons say if it is a small/medium/large pizza and it is required for the pizza image to change it's dimensions depending on the size that is being clicked. This is what I have so far:

```
function togglesize()
{
    var size;
    if (document.getElementById("small").checked)
    {
        size = 400px;
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("medium").checked)
    {
        size = 600px;
    }
    else
    {
        size = 800px;
    }

    document.getElementById("crust").style.height = size;
    document.getElementById("crust").style.width = size;
    document.getElementById("cheesea").style.height = size;
    document.getElementById("cheesea").style.width = size;
    document.getElementById("olivesa").style.height = size;
    document.getElementById("olivesa").style.width = size;
    document.getElementById("bacona").style.height = size;
    document.getElementById("bacona").style.width = size;
    document.getElementById("pepperonia").style.height = size;
    document.getElementById("pepperonia").style.width = size;
}
```

But, whenever I save and attempt to use my webpage everything stops working. When I delete this from my HTML document the webpage works the way it should, but I just can't change the size of the pizza image.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The width and height are text values. "px" is not a Javascript recognized measure, but CSS:

```
//Note the quotes
size = "400px";
```

Comment: Also, query for each element once, storing it in a local variable. Hopefully, Don can update his answer with this suggestion.